# Why doesn't the timestamp parameter get passed along with the request?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, floating-point, httprequest

With a request,four parameters need to passsed, out of which only 3 are getting passed. The parameter `timestamp` doesn't get passed. What could be the reason for this?

```
$.ajax( {
                    url : 'http://localhost:8081/Football/FeFeed',
                    data : {
                        playernumber : $('#playernumber_goal').val(),
                        timestamp : $('#match').get(0).currrentTime,
                        event : 'goal',
                        team : 'team-name'
                    },
                    type : 'GET'
  })     .done(function(message){

         }).fail(function(message) {

         });
```

Html for #match :

```
<video id="match" width="440" controls>
                    <source src="match.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    <source src="match.ogg" type="video/ogg">
                    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

The URL formed is: `http://localhost:8081/Football/FeFeed?playernumber=22&event=goal&team=team-name`

*Edit : I am able to pass a static variable like `100.232`*

Comment: try to pass a static value for the key timestamp like "17h15" or somthing you expect

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil I need to send a float value

Comment: Maybe $('#match').get(0).currrentTime causes a problem.

So pass a static float value. and check the new build URL

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil able to pass successfully.

Comment: so your problem is as i expected.
now try to alert the  $('#match').get(0).currrentTime . You ll find it something wrong.
What do you want from this jquery expression ?

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil the current time of video

Comment: what's the result of `console.log($('#match').get(0).currrentTime)` ? And what version of `jQuery` are you using ?

Comment: @SuhailGupta so that's your problem, if the value is `undefined` it won't get passed in the AJAX call. Are you sure that `$('#match')` and `$('#match').get(0)` are refering to your video element ? Don't you have 2 HTML elements with the ID `match` ? If yes, it's incorrect.

Comment: @pomeh no, i have only one element. also other calls like `$('#match').get(0).pause();` are working fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`currrentTime` or `currentTime`?!!!

Comment: wow nice catch ! There is 3 `r` in your `currrentTime` @SuhailGupta, the spec says it must have only 2.

Comment: @N K . i think i's about concentration test :-)

Comment: @Med.Amine.Touil, Obviously ;)

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to pass the video time try this .

```
var tempVideo= document.getElementById("match");
var tempTime=tempVideo.currentTime;
```

and in your ajax post

```
timestamp : tempTime
```

Comment: @Suhail Gupta hope it helps

Comment: `$('#match').get(0).currrentTime`

Comment: I usually use the $('#match').get(0) to get the object id. So no idea if $('#match').get(0).currrentTime works. Did you try my answer.
And to know what happens try to alert $('#match').get(0).currrentTime

Comment: gives out undefined for my thing.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Try my answer. It 's pure javascript.

And if it works it 's problem of juqery version or browser type